# MongoDb (Mongoose) aggregation issue with $lookup and $project

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I am a beginner in MongoDB and am working on my personal project. I am trying to populate employees field for teamSurveyForms, but it is returning Array(0) for teamSurveyForm.employees.Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong?

```
            const pipeline = [
                {
                  $lookup: {
                    from: 'departments',
                    localField: 'department',
                    foreignField: '_id',
                    as: 'departmentData',
                  },
                },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: 'forms',
                        localField: 'forms',
                        foreignField: '_id',
                        as: 'formsData',
                    },
                },
                {
                    $lookup:{
                      from: 'employees',
                      localField: 'teamSurveyForms.employees',
                      foreignField: '_id',
                      as: 'teamFormEmployees',
                    },
                },
                {
                  $unwind: {
                    path: '$departmentData',
                    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
                  },
                },
                {
                  $project: {
                      fName: 1,
                      lName: 1,
                      empCode: 1,
                      email: 1,
                      password:1,
                      empType: 1,
                      designation: 1,
                      DOJ:1,
                      department: '$departmentData.name',
                      selfSurveyForms: {$cond:
                        {
                            if:employeeWithForm,
                            then:{
                                $map:{
                                    input:{
                                        $filter:{
                                            input:'$formsData',
                                            as:'selfForm',
                                            cond:{$eq:['$$selfForm.FType','Self']}
                                        }
                                    },
                                    as:'selfForm',
                                    in:{
                                        _id:'$$selfForm._id',
                                        FType:'$$selfForm.FType',
                                        title:'$$selfForm.title',
                                        description:'$$selfForm.description',
                                        department: '$departmentData.name',
                                        employees:[],
                                    }
                                },
                            },
                            else:null
                        }
                      },
                      teamSurveyForms: {$cond:
                        {
                            if:employeeWithForm,
                            then:{
                                $map: {
                                    input: {
                                        $filter:{
                                            input:'$formsData',
                                            as:'teamForm',
                                            cond:{$eq:['$$teamForm.FType','Team']}
                                        }
                                    },
                                    as:'teamForm',
                                    in:{
                                        _id:'$$teamForm._id',
                                        FType:'$$teamForm.FType',
                                        title:'$$teamForm.title',
                                        description:'$$teamForm.description',
                                        department: '$departmentData.department',
                                        employees:{
                                            $map: {
                                                input: '$teamFormEmployees',
                                                as: 'employee',
                                                in: {
                                                    _id:'$$employee._id',
                                                    name: {$concat: ['$$employee.fName', ' ', '$$employee.lName']},
                                                }
                                            },
                                        },
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            else:null
                        }
                      },
                  },
                },
                {
                    $match: findQueryData, // Apply the conditions for searching
                },
                {
                    $skip: (page - 1) * items_per_page, // Skip records based on page number
                },
                {
                    $limit: Number(items_per_page), // Limit the number of records per page
                },
            ];

            data=await FormModel.aggregate(pipeline);
```

I want to get data with all fields like fName,lName,empCode,email,password,empType,designation, DOJ, department and forms split into selfSurveyForms and teamSurveyForms and in both forms I need FType, title, description, department and employees. In selfSurveyForms, I am sending employees as empty array but in teamSurveyForms I need employees (which is an array of ids of employee) by populating it with employee collection.

selfSurveyForms and teamSurveyForms both are array.